# StyleCop for SQL Development

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, standards, stylecop

I'm having to rewrite a lot of SP and Functions (over 200 sp) that have been written by number of different people over 6 year period. I'm want to find plugin like StyleCop that can help enforce some sort of standard that I can adhere to and than let other people developers use.

I'm already using RedGate for formatting the SP and Functions but I need something that can set standards like parameter and local variable naming, force variable declaration before any set statements and etc. I heard of several tools (Sonar, SQLAuditor, SQL Best Practice Analyzer). Just not sure what is the best tool. It does not have to be free.

When answering please provide the name of the product, link to the webpage and why you like to use it and what features it provides.

Standards to enforce:
Use of alias in all select statements.
Declaration of all variables at the start before any work. 
Naming all CTE alias more than 10 character, names that mean something
Naming of temp tables and variables 
Setting NOCOUNT ON 
The comments vs commented out code.

Comment: How about reverse engineering your database into a Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013 **database project** ([see SQL Server Data Tools for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx))? That should give you a lot of tool support for your T-SQL code.... not sure if it supports StyleCop, but it supports things like refactoring

Comment: How about SQLCop? http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/sqlcop-a-tool-to-highlight-potential-pro

Comment: +1 on SQLCop (although I am a little biased).

Comment: I have reviewed the SQLCop and i'm not seeing the functionality that I'm looking for. It is great for analyzing schema but I can't find what I need for procedure standardization. Don't get me wrong, it is great tool for and has many functions, just not what I need.

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question and add examples of the 'standards' you wish to check and enforce on your procedures?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SQL Enlight. It is a commercial tool, but I believe can help you accomplish what you want.

The tool has a static analysis feature which you can use for analyzing your stored procedures, T-SQL files and even entire databases. It comes with more than 100 analysis rules, but if want and you can also define your own rules.

It can integrate with SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio, can be used from the command line, and also provides MSBuild and NAnt tasks which you can use in automated builds.

Here is a link to the tool's site: http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/